# I want to use a group by for a nvarchar data type

Tags: mysql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

My goal is to create a query that can group by 3 respective survey types and their respective values. the columns are The date is automatically updated every couple of days, the Survey type broken down into different survey types being survey a , survey b and survey c. These surveys can be either labeled sent (meaning the customer is in possession and has not completed it) or it can be labeled received(meaning the customer has completed it and the information is received.Each of the survey strings begin with the same 4  characters  XXX- . This is where my use of wildcard % comes into play. the format of the survey type is XXX-YY-SENT or "XXX-YY-RECIEVED" .The YY are distinct to the specific survey type. The value column gives the total number of surveys completed by the date which is updated by the system every 2 weeks.  My goal is to group the data by its survey type in order to be able to create a stacked column chart in ssrs showing the difference between sent and received surveys. (which I already have a good idea on how to execute. The issue is developing the query in order to pull the data and group it by Survey X (Group being survey x-SENT and survey x-recieved) and Survey Y (Group being survey y-SENT and survey y-recieved) and Survey Z (Group being survey z-SENT and survey z-recieved).here is example data from table SurveyInfo. This is the query i use to pull my data:

```
 SELECT [Date]  ,[SurveyType]  ,[Value]
 FROM SurveyInfo]
  WHERE Date IN (SELECT max(Date) FROM SurveyInfo) and SurveyType like '%XXX%'
```

(this is where i would like to group the data by survey type) 
this is the data result.

```
Date ,                          SurveyType,              Value 

2017-06-02 08:00:02.270     XXX-AA-SENT-WITHIN-2YR          1000.0000
2017-06-02 08:00:02.270     XXX-AA-RECEIVED-WITHIN-2YR        900.0000
2017-06-02 08:00:02.270     XXX-BB-SENT-WITHIN-2YR          1200.0000
2017-06-02 08:00:02.270     XXX-BB-RECEIVED-2YR             800.0000
2017-06-02 08:00:02.270     XXX-CC-SENT-WITHIN-2YR          500.0000
2017-06-02 08:00:02.270     XXX-CC-RECEIVED-WITHIN-2YR       400.0000
```

Comment: I've seen shorter RFPs. What is going on here? You really need to boil this down into a coherent question people can help you with.

Comment: I look at that wall of text and my mind refuses to read it.

Answer (score 0):

That was hard to read through but I think I understand what you want.  Does the below start to help you out?

```
if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#test') is not null drop table #test
create table #test
(
    dateVal datetime,
    SurveyType nvarchar(500),
    SurveyValue decimal(36,4)
)

insert into #test
values('2017-06-02 08:00:02.270','XXX-AA-SENT-WITHIN-2YR',1000.0000),
 ('2017-06-02 08:00:02.270','XXX-AA-RECEIVED-WITHIN-2YR', 900.0000),
 ('2017-06-02 08:00:02.270','XXX-BB-SENT-WITHIN-2YR',          1200.0000),
 ('2017-06-02 08:00:02.270','XXX-BB-RECEIVED-2YR',             800.0000),
 ('2017-06-02 08:00:02.270','XXX-CC-SENT-WITHIN-2YR',          500.0000),
 ('2017-06-02 08:00:02.270','XXX-CC-RECEIVED-WITHIN-2YR',       400.0000)

SELECT  
    substring(SurveyType,5,2) as SurveyType,
    case when SurveyType like '%SENT%' then 'SENT' else 'RECEIVED' END as SENT_RECEIVED,
    sum(SurveyValue) as SumSurveyValue
 FROM #test 
GROUP BY 
    substring(SurveyType,5,2)  ,
    case when SurveyType like '%SENT%' then 'SENT' else 'RECEIVED' END
ORDER BY 
    SurveyType,
    SENT_RECEIVED
```